# Count tokens in dataframe text pandas

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df
    review_text
0                                           love it.
1                                           amazing!
2                                               love
3                           sounds good great price!
4  after two hours, wife asked turn off. even bos...
```

And I have a list of lists containing above text tokenized:

```
texts[0:5]

Out[183]: 
[['love'],
 ['amazing'],
 ['love'],
 ['sounds', 'good', 'great', 'price'],
 ['two',
  'hours',
  'wife',
  'asked',
  'turn',
  'even',
  'bose',
  'products',
  'sound',
  'better']]
```

Each list in `texts` corresponds to a row in the df.

What I want is to count the tokens in the list in each document and create a long dataframe with one row for each token and retain the index from the df:

```
sample = pd.DataFrame(data=[['love', 0, 1], ['amazing', 1, 1], ['love', 2, 1], ['sounds', 3, 1], ['good', 3, 1], ['great', 3, 1], ['price', 3, 1], ['two', 4, 1], ['hours', 4, 1], ['wife', 4, 1], ['asked', 4, 1]], columns=['texts', 'index', 'freq'])

sample.set_index('index', inplace=True)

sample
Out[192]: 
         texts  freq
index               
0         love     1
1      amazing     1
2         love     1
3       sounds     1
3         good     1
3        great     1
3        price     1
4          two     1
4        hours     1
4         wife     1
4        asked     1
```

I was trying to make a dictionary from the nested list with count of each token like this:

```
from collections import Counter
sample_dict = dict()

for i in texts:
    sample_dict.update(Counter(i))
```

But I wasn't sure of how to make the dataframe long and combine it with the counts in the dictionary.

Comment: This looks like a problem that needs an involved solution. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I was trying a dictionary approach but was unsure of how to merge the dictionary with the dataframe. I've updated that in the questiton.

Comment: Also, why does "love" appear twice with a separate entry each time?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ because it corresponds to two different rows from the `df`. 'love' is in row_index 0 and 2.

Comment: same like unlistify to me  ..

Comment: Okay... but why is it twice in the _token list_ too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**

```
pd.Series(Counter([(i, t) for i, l in enumerate(texts) for t in l]))

0  love        1
1  amazing     1
2  love        1
3  good        1
   great       1
   price       1
   sounds      1
4  asked       1
   better      1
   bose        1
   even        1
   hours       1
   products    1
   sound       1
   turn        1
   two         1
   wife        1
dtype: int64
```

---

**Option 2**

```
pd.Series(texts).apply(pd.value_counts).fillna(0).astype(int)

   amazing  asked  better  bose  even  good  great  hours  love  price  products  sound  sounds  turn  two  wife
0        0      0       0     0     0     0      0      0     1      0         0      0       0     0    0     0
1        1      0       0     0     0     0      0      0     0      0         0      0       0     0    0     0
2        0      0       0     0     0     0      0      0     1      0         0      0       0     0    0     0
3        0      0       0     0     0     1      1      0     0      1         0      0       1     0    0     0
4        0      1       1     1     1     0      0      1     0      0         1      1       0     1    1     1
```

Comment: I need to match the tokens back to the index of the `df`. If the df column has 5 words, I need 5 rows for it with the same index and the count of the tokens from the list in the df. I'll make some edits to explain this better.

Comment: You say that... but if you can't do it from what I've shown you then I don't know what you mean.  That implies that you should show us what you mean.

Comment: That solved it ! the indexes match now. I can join the df with the series.

Answer (score 2):

Or try this

```
df=df.A.apply(pd.Series).T.unstack().reset_index().dropna().drop('level_1',1).set_index('level_0')
df.groupby([df.index.get_level_values(0),0]).size()


level_0  0       
0        love        1
1        amazing     1
2        love        1
3        good        1
         great       1
         price       1
         sounds      1
4        asked       1
         better      1
         bose        1
         even        1
         hours       1
         products    1
         sound       1
         turn        1
         two         1
         wife        1
```

---

Data Input

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[['love'],
 ['amazing'],
 ['love'],
 ['sounds', 'good', 'great', 'price'],
 ['two',
  'hours',
  'wife',
  'asked',
  'turn',
  'even',
  'bose',
  'products',
  'sound',
  'better']]})
```

Comment: Thanks Wen, I need to count the tokens in the nested list in the df column. Can't use the df directly . .

Comment: @vagabond also , the out put for my solution is pd.Serise .

Answer (score 0):

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

word_counts = []
def run(data):
    counts = {}
    data_grouped = data.groupby('community')
        for community, group in data_grouped:
        corpus = community.values.flatten()

        vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
        X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
        temp = pd.DataFrame(X.toarray(), columns=vectorizer.get_feature_names())
        temp['community'] = group
        word_counts += [temp]
    return counts

word_counts = pd.concat(word_counts, axis=0)
```